# Cartoon show from the early 2000s about a rookie cop in a world where everyone is a robot shaped as a sphere

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, robots

I'm trying to find a cartoon show from the early 2000s, that's similar to the *Pac-Man* cartoon in regards to animation. It's about this rookie cop in a world where everyone is a robot shaped as a sphere. The man character is all red, while everyone else is plain silver or black. That's all I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 11):

Could this be [*RollBots*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RollBots)? It's about a police force consisting of spherical robots.

Comment: And of course, the inevitable joke about the policeman's balls; https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/great-balls-of-misfire/